# Updating table in multiple schemas in single transaction

Tags: jdbc, transactions, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I have a situation where I need to update tables in different schemas in a single transaction.I can either use a plain JDBC or a Spring JDBCtemplate.

Any suggestions as to how I can achieve this.Thanks.

Ravi

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you make your database connection from java with a specific user (say JAVA_USR or something like that), and ask your DBA for the proper grants over the destination schemas.  Your DBA will like too to know that all the accesses from java applications are made from the same user, since it will make monitoring easier for them.

This way you can send the following alter statements through JDBC or SpringTemplate:

```
ALTER TABLE JOE.TABLE_1 ADD NAME VARCHAR2(80)
ALTER TABLE MARVIN.TABLE_2 ADD SURNAME VARCHAR2(100)
ALTER TABLE JACK.TABLE_3 ADD ADDRESS VARCHAR2(75)
...
```

If all the schemas are in the same database, you should be able to do your job in the same transaction in either of the ways you have asked about.